# Enabling incoming email for SharePoint document library without Active Directory or Exchange?

Tags: 2010, administration, configuration, incoming-email

This is a high level question. Can I enable incoming email for SharePoint without any involvement from Active Directory or Exchange?

From what I have read, integration with Active Directory or Exchange contacts is an option. I don't want the lists to show up in the address book, I just want them to work.

It's my understanding that if you say you do NOT want SharePoint Directory Management to create distribution groups and contacts, that there would not be any need for SharePoint to be able to write to Active Directory. Is this correct?

Comment: I have been using incoming email and i've had to use exchange and the of course AD.
If you don't have exchange do you have any sort of emailing system?

Comment: @naijacoder We do have exchange, but the admins don't want SharePoint using it. I will ask a new question about HOW to "get the email delivered to the SMTP service running on a SharePoint server."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're correct. AD/Exchange isn't a requirement for SharePoint incoming email.

As long as you can get the email delivered to the SMTP service running on a SharePoint server.

The "only" advantage using AD/Exchange is the option automatic creation of the mailbox when a list is enabled for incomming emails.

You can just follow the Simple scdenarion of [Incoming Email Configuration - MOSS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvagan/archive/2008/01/26/incoming-email-configuration-moss.aspx) which is also valid for SP2010

Comment: I've added a new question asking how is "the email delivered to the SMTP service running on a SharePoint"?http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44136/how-does-internal-email-get-to-the-smtp-client-of-a-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found your other, differently-worded post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44136/how-does-internal-email-get-to-the-smtp-client-of-a-sharepoint-server/51254#51254) and answered it extensively.  It might help you.